microbit KITRONIK :MOVE motor line following
I just bought KITRONIK :MOVE motor for my kids and have problem with line following.
I think the problem is that the line following sensor is not sending data fast enough. Robot can go forward, but when the direction of the line changes, it crosses it and reacts late when it is already absolutely outside the line.
I thought the problem was in my code. I found the code on the line following directly from the KITRONIK - last page:
https://resources.kitronik.co.uk/pdf/5683-move-motor-microbit-additional-resources-line-following.pdf


    

left = 0
    right = 0
    difference = 0
    speed = 15
    
    def on_forever():
        global right, left, difference
        right = Kitronik_Move_Motor.read_sensor(Kitronik_Move_Motor.LfSensor.RIGHT)
        left = Kitronik_Move_Motor.read_sensor(Kitronik_Move_Motor.LfSensor.LEFT)
        difference = abs(left - right)
        basic.show_number(Kitronik_Move_Motor.read_sensor(Kitronik_Move_Motor.LfSensor.RIGHT))
        serial.write_number(difference)
        serial.write_line("")
        if difference > 30:
            if left >= right:
                Kitronik_Move_Motor.motor_off(Kitronik_Move_Motor.Motors.MOTOR_RIGHT)
                Kitronik_Move_Motor.motor_on(Kitronik_Move_Motor.Motors.MOTOR_LEFT,
                    Kitronik_Move_Motor.MotorDirection.FORWARD,
                    speed)
            else:
                Kitronik_Move_Motor.motor_off(Kitronik_Move_Motor.Motors.MOTOR_LEFT)
                Kitronik_Move_Motor.motor_on(Kitronik_Move_Motor.Motors.MOTOR_RIGHT,
                    Kitronik_Move_Motor.MotorDirection.FORWARD,
                    speed)
        else:
            Kitronik_Move_Motor.move(Kitronik_Move_Motor.DriveDirections.FORWARD, speed)
        basic.forever(on_forever)

and i still have the same problem. I added serial.write to set the difference correctly and tried to make a thicker line but nothing solved the problem.
Do you see any errors in the code or the error is in line following sensor in KITRONIK :MOVE ?
